# Set image height to 100% and width to auto not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put an image inside a div, I have put the `width: auto;` and `height: 100%;`. This is working fine in Chrome and FireFox but not in Safari and I dare to check in IE! What should I change??

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="loggo-title" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/header.png" height="100%" width="auto"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried to make it the css way with

```
img { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Hannes

Comment: are you trying to put image 100% your div?? YES why not use background-image in your div?

Comment: when you tried with css did you remove the height and width attributes from your img tag? if not try that.  Also I don't think href is a valid attribute for div (but I may be wrong)

Comment: Oho that certainly a silly mistake, Thanks @Pete! Yes I did remove width and height attributes and sadly it didn't work either. :(

Comment: Just noticed your `.loggo-title` only contains your image so unless you have specifically set a height for that div then your image will be set to 0 height as your div will have no height (and your image will be 100% of 0)

Answer (score -1):

Try width 100% as well if you want the image to stay the same aspect ration

Comment: Thanks for answearing so fast! The problem is it being a text image, so I need it to stay in a certain width and only depend on height. If I put 100% width and height auto, it will be really large....

Comment: Then try the image at 50% then it will always be half, I would suggest playing arround with the percentages because with width being auto, it could look very distorted in a variety of browsers @HannesH

Comment: This doesn't maintain aspect ratio for me, which make sense if the parent has different dimensions.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried doesnt't writing anything on width?
I will try writting:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/header.png" height="100%" width=""/>

img { height:100% }
```

It works for me!